# java: Using a remote JMS provider

Tags: java, jms, provider

I have a tomcat web application. It uses a couple of remote modules. One of the modules publishes some messages (about it states) into queue. I need to read it. how can I do it?
As far as I know I need realization of IninialContext to obtain remote queue by name, right? Haven't found any useful materials on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this link on activemq site: http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html take a look at class `Server` and `Client` for help in writing JMS `Consumer` and `Producer`.

Comment: Thanks. It was quite easy: I filled Property object and create InitialContext using it. All the following things was like in examples.